# What does -p argument do in this command "/bin/bash -p "

Tags: bash, users, root

if we have the **SETUID** and **SETGID** set for the bash binary.

```
-rwsr-sr-x  1 root root   108424 Mar 10  2020  /bin/bash
```

and we execute the command: `/bin/bash -p`
we will find ourselves escalated to they root user.
I have been trying to understand what -p does from the bash man page but I couldn't, and I understand how Real and Effective User and Group IDs work.

Comment: Sadly, `-p` is not mentioned at the top where options should be described, but ater on it says: _"If the shell is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the -p option is not supplied, no startup  files  are  read,
       shell  functions are not inherited from the environment, the SHELLOPTS variable, if it appears in the environment, is ignored, **and the effective user id is set to
       the real user id**.  If the -p option is supplied at invocation, the startup behavior is the same, but the effective user id is not reset"_